# Map return type from input generic type in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I have a function that returns IMyInterface

```
fun getValue(type: Types): IMyInterface? {}
```

But I have to always cast the return type in this way before I can use it:

```
  getValue(Types.TypeInt)?.let { value ->
    val usableVale = MyInterfaceAsInt.cast(value)
    // more code...
  }
```

`MyInterfaceAsInt` implements `IMyInterface` and I have no control over them.

The casting always depend of the input, so

```
Types.TypeInt -> MyInterfaceAsInt.cast(value)
Types.TypeLong -> MyInterfaceAsLong.cast(value)
...etc
```

Is there a way to define somthing like `fun <T = Types> getValue(type: T)` in a way that the return type can be inferred from `type` ?

I would like to do the casting inside `getValue`.

Comment: Not enough info here to tell what you're doing. How do you know these casts are safe? Is `getValue` returning something from a collection? Is something like MyInterfaceAsInt a subtype of IMyInterface? What do these `cast` functions do exactly?

Comment: @Tenfour04 yes, I suppose the cast function takes the IMyInterface object and converts it to an instance of MyInterfaceAsInt. As I said it is external and sadly the Java code there is not well documented. These cast are safe. getValue returns an object from an external library asset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like `Types.TypesInt`/`Long`/etc. are simply instances of the same type `Types`, not different types; and in `fun <T> getValue(type: T)`, `T` has to be a *type*. So it doesn't seem to be possible.

But I would probably go the other way and define functions like

```
fun getValueAsInt(): MyInterfaceAsInt? = getValue(Types.TypeInt)?.let { MyInterfaceAsInt.cast(it) }
fun getValueAsLong(): MyInterfaceAsLong? = getValue(Types.TypeLong)?.let { MyInterfaceAsLong.cast(it) }
...
```

Another alternative which could be useful at least when the type can be inferred:

```
@Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
inline fun <reified T : MyInterface> getValue(): T? = when(T::class) {
    MyInterfaceAsInt::class -> getValue(Types.TypeInt)?.let { MyInterfaceAsInt.cast(it) }
    MyInterfaceAsLong::class -> getValue(Types.TypeLong)?.let { MyInterfaceAsLong.cast(it) }
    ...
} as T
```

Comment: That is what I am doing right now (with a couple of `{}` more)

Comment: I've added another alternative.